# Node.js I am fetching a JSON like data but I can't use it

Tags: node.js, api

I am fetching some data like this:

```
async function fetchD (){
    var res =await fetch("https://api.jikan.moe/v3/genre/anime/11") ;
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    // console.log(data["type"])
    // console.log(data["name"])
    // console.log(data["mal_id"])
}
fetchD();
```

it gives an output:

```
{
  request_hash: 'request:genre:6aa6fdf978701575c8f4a77a3a30de63d91d9b40',
  request_cached: true,
  request_cache_expiry: 73044,
  mal_url: {
    mal_id: 11,
    type: 'anime',
    name: 'Game Anime',
    url: 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/11/Game'
  },
  item_count: 346,
  anime: [
.
.
.continues...
```

Data looks like JSON but, it's first part doesn't have quotes so I can't stringify or JSON.parse. Is there a way to access this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already parsing the data you're receiving to a JavaScript object using the `const data = await res.json();` line, that's why it doesn't have quotes.

You're also not accessing the data with the correct properties, `data["type"]`, `data["name"]` and `data["mal_id"]` don't exist in the "root" of your object but instead are in another object (the `mal_url` object) inside the data, so you'd access those using `data.mal_url.type`, `data.mal_url.name` and `data.mal_url.mal_id`.

Or using the bracket syntax: `data["mal_url"]["type"]`, `data["mal_url"]["name"]` and `data["mal_url"]["mal_id"]`.

So the fixed code would look like this:

```js
async function fetchD() {
  const res = await fetch("https://api.jikan.moe/v3/genre/anime/11");
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data.mal_url.type);
  console.log(data.mal_url.name);
  console.log(data.mal_url.mal_id);
}

fetchD();
```